# Shortcut for "Show all windows"

Tags: linux-mint

Can I set a shortcut for "Show all windows" feature in hot corners? In Ubuntu this feature is more advanced, there you can type name of the window to select it.[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a pretty old question, but still it was the first one I hit when searching for the same thing.

Apparently in [previous versions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335001/128015) (pre 19) it was called "Toggle scale" in the keyboard shortcuts settings panel.

On Mint 19.1 Cinnamon it's labeled as "Show the window selection screen" under "General" in the keyboard shortcuts settings.

The default binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.