# What is hotkey in Linux Mint for "Show All Windows"?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-shortcuts

I noted it is possible set a number of hotkeys in Linux Mint 17.1 using the *keyboard* application, but there's not possibility to set the hotkey "Show All Windows"; you can only set a button using Preferences -> Hot Corners.

You can set customize hotkey too, but I'm not able to do that. Browsing on the internet, I did not find anything as tutorial, wiki,... to do that.

Can someone suggest what I have to do setting that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its name is "Toggle Scale" on the keyboard shortcuts settings.

Answer (score 11):

For `Linux Mint 18 Sarah` ,<`ctrl+alt+down-key`> worked to display all the open windows in the current desktop. To view all the windows in all the desktops, use <`ctrl+ alr+ up-key`>.

Should work for `Ubuntu` too.

Comment: Thx! it works for me on Debian 9 + cinnamon :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its toggle scale under general in keyboard shortcuts.

Default is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (<kbd>ALT</kbd>/<kbd>shift</kbd>) <kbd>down</kbd>, but not to sure.

Answer (score 2):

On Mint 19.1 Cinnamon it's labeled as "Show the window selection screen" under "General" in the keyboard shortcuts settings.

The default binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

[image]